# Two forms, one page codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this delete and add admin account function now in CodeIgniter. But i want that it works together. Is there any way I can solve this? The delete and save work properly separate tho.

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // model aanroepen
        $this->load->model('Admin_model', '', TRUE);


        // see if there is post
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
                    $username = $this->input->post("username");
                    $password = $this->input->post("password");

                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) {

                        $new_admin = new Admin_model();
                        $new_admin->Admin_name = $username;
                        $new_admin->Admin_password = $password;

                        $this->Admin_model->save($new_admin);


                }
        }

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

            $userid = $this->input->post("id_admin");

            $this->Admin_model->delete($userid);


        }


        $tweets = $this->Admin_model->get_all();
        $viewdata = [
            "tweets" => $tweets
        ];


        $this->load->view('admin/admin', $viewdata);

    }


}
```

View:

```
<?php echo validation_errors() ?>

    <h1>Create new admin</h1>

   <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>

        <button type="submit" id="admin_submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


    <h1>Delete admin</h1>


    <?php foreach($tweets as $t): ?>
        <?php echo "<p>" . $t['admin_name']."</p> "; ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id_admin" value="<?php echo $t['admin_id'] ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
        </form>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what problrm u facing or which error u getting?

Comment: When i click the delete button, It will show the validation errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to do both work together Then please put Some hidden value in both form and get that value and put validation according to that hidden value or Submit button which button was pressed .. by isset function Like

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])) // or check hidden field value here 
{ 
/* here put save button validation  Or validation according for hidden value */

}else if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
/*  Delete validation  OR other validation */ 
}
```

In Your controller

Answer (score 1):

yes you can add name tag on save and delete button in view like

```
<button type="submit" name="save" id="admin_submit">Submit</button>
```

now get this to controller like

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
  //here your code of save only its work for when you click save button
}
```

same like for delete and work fine on same function

Answer (score 1):

Both of your method checks are post, so when you POST your delete form, it actually goes into your first method.

Do this check, which checks if you clicked a delete button:

```
$is_delete = $this->input->post('delete');
```

And change:

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
```

to:

```
 if (isset($is_delete))
```

Do the same thing for the save action:

```
<button type="submit" name="save_admin" id="admin_submit">Submit</button>
```

Do this check, which checks if you clicked a delete button:

```
$is_save = $this->input->post('save_admin');
```

And change:

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
```

to:

```
 if (isset($is_save))
```

That way you don't call the method everytime you get a POST request.